# Sass maps - Responsive Typography

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

I'm trying to write a Sass map to make my headers responsive.

I often use http://type-scale.com/ to set my header font sizes so for e.g. using that my h1 would be 3.998rem.

The problem with that is at mobile sizes it's too big.

You could write media queries for h1 to h6 but that would be too much code.

I've written an example which works for just h1 tags but how could I make it work h1 through to h6 without writing multiple maps?

Cheers

**SASS**

```
$headers-responsive: (
    null: 1rem,
    480px: 1.5rem,
    768px: 2rem,
    992px: 3rem,
    1200px: 4rem
);

@mixin font-scale($font-scaler) {
    @each $breakpoint, $value in $font-scaler {
        @if($breakpoint == null) {
            font-size: $value;
        } @else {
            @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
                font-size: $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

h1 {
    @include font-scale($headers-responsive);
}
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
font-size:1rem;
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
h1 {
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
}

@media (min-width:768px){
h1 {
  font-size:2rem;
}
}

@media (min-width:992px){
h1 {
  font-size:3rem;
}
}

@media (min-width:1200px){
h1 {
  font-size:4rem;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a "multiplier" parameter to `font-scale()`?

Say you want `h2` to be 80% of `h1`, and `h3` to be 60% of `h1`:

```
...

@mixin font-scale($font-scaler, $multiplier: 1) {
    @each $breakpoint, $value in $font-scaler {
        @if($breakpoint == null) {
            font-size: $value * $multiplier;
        } @else {
            @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
                font-size: $value * $multiplier;
            }
        }
    }
}

h1 {
    @include font-scale($headers-responsive);
}

h2 {
    @include font-scale($headers-responsive, .8);
}

h3 {
    @include font-scale($headers-responsive, .6);
}
```